# conditional ng-required collectively checking 3 input boxes is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

**Angular v 1.6.8**

I have a form with 3 input box where a user enters the numbers and my requirement is that one of the input box must have at least some value ( greater than 0 ) but this is not working.

I bind a method with `ng-required` for all 3 input box and this method checks all 3 input box value which evaluates to *true/false*. In this method I am using native javascript method [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any one input box is having a value greater than 0 than rest of input box is not required ( i.e. ng-required evaluated to false )

I have also added one directive which controls what max and min value for the input box.

Now my issues are

**1.** When user enters 0 for all 3 input box, the form became valid which is not right. ( this is my main issue)
**2.** If I enter more than the max value in input box than directive gives validation error properly BUT with $parse key also ( `$error": { "validRange": true, "parse": true })` )? Why is this coming?

**3.** All error messages appear together which is not expected behavior.

Kindly help me. Here is the [demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bhoe6M) with the issue.

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('AppController', function($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      angular.extend(vm, {
        formdata: {
          username: "",
          vehicles: {
            bike: null,
            car: null,
            cycle: null
          }
        }
      });

      vm.isOptionsRequired = function(item) {
        // console.log("isOptionsRequired", item);
        var arr = Object.values(item);
        console.log("arr", arr);
        var final = arr.some(function(option) {
          return option > 0;
        });
        // console.log("final", final);
        return !final;
      };

      vm.updateForm = function() {
        console.log('updateForm called', vm.formdata);
      }

    }).directive('validateNumber', function($timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          validateNumber: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
          function checkOut(text) {
            if (text < scope.validateNumber.min || text > scope.validateNumber.max) {
              console.info("if inside directive");
              ngModel.$setValidity('validRange', false);
            } else {
              console.info("else inside directive");
              ngModel.$setValidity('validRange', true);
              if (text) {
                var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                if (transformedInput !== text) {
                  ngModel.$setValidity('validNumber', false);
                  angular.element(element).css({
                    'background-color': '#ffc7c7'
                  });
                  ngModel.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                  ngModel.$render();
                } else {
                  $timeout(function() {
                    angular.element(element).css({
                      'background-color': '#ffffff',
                      'transition': 'background-color 40ms ease-out',
                      '-ms-transition': 'background-color 40ms linear',
                      '-webkit-transition': 'background-color 40ms linear'
                    });
                  }, 100);
                  ngModel.$setValidity('validNumber', true);
                }
                return transformedInput;
              }
              return undefined;
            }
          }
          ngModel.$parsers.unshift(checkOut);
        }
      };
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<body class="container" ng-controller="AppController as vm">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="wheelForm" novalidate="">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error': wheelForm.username.$touched && wheelForm.username.$invalid }">
          <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.formdata.username" required="" />
          <div ng-if="wheelForm.username.$touched && wheelForm.username.$invalid" ng-messages="wheelForm.username.$error" class="has-error">
            <span ng-message="required">Please enter name.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="col-md-4"># of Bikes</label>{{wheelForm.vehicle_bike | json }}
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error': wheelForm.vehicle_bike.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_bike.$invalid }">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter 0 for no vehicles" name="vehicle_bike" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.formdata.vehicles.bike" ng-required="vm.isOptionsRequired(vm.formdata.vehicles)" validate-number="{min:0, max:10}" />
          <div ng-messages="wheelForm.vehicle_bike.$error" ng-if="wheelForm.vehicle_bike.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_bike.$invalid" class="text-danger">
            <!-- <span ng-message="parse">Enter 0 if no bike servlet required</span> -->
            <span ng-message="validRange">Number must be between 0 and 10.</span>
            <span ng-message="required">Please enter Number.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="col-md-4"># of Cars</label>{{wheelForm.vehicle_car | json }}
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error': wheelForm.vehicle_car.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_car.$invalid }">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter 0 for no vehicles" name="vehicle_car" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.formdata.vehicles.car" ng-required="vm.isOptionsRequired(vm.formdata.vehicles)" validate-number="{min:0, max:10}" />
          <div ng-messages="wheelForm.vehicle_car.$error" ng-if="wheelForm.vehicle_car.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_car.$invalid" class="text-danger">
            <span ng-message="validRange">Number must be between 0 and 10.</span>
            <span ng-message="required">Please enter Number.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="col-md-4"># of Cycles</label>{{wheelForm.vehicle_cycle | json }}
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error': wheelForm.vehicle_cycle.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_cycle.$invalid }">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter 0 for no vehicles" name="vehicle_cycle" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.formdata.vehicles.cycle" ng-required="vm.isOptionsRequired(vm.formdata.vehicles)" validate-number="{min:0, max:10}" />
          <div ng-messages="wheelForm.vehicle_cycle.$error" ng-if="wheelForm.vehicle_cycle.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_cycle.$invalid" class="text-danger">
            <span ng-message="validRange">Number must be between 0 and 10.</span>
            <span ng-message="required">Please enter Number.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-actions m-t-lg text-center">
        <button ng-disabled="wheelForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-block btn-success" ng-click="vm.updateForm()">
          Update
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can use ng-pattern,ng-maxlength and ng-minlength for validations

Comment: by that way user can add decimal value and `+`, `e`, and `.` too as well which I don't want. how we can set maxlength and minlength? there is no length issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as I miss the understanding of ng-required, if there is some value ( whether it is 0 ) in input box than ng-required is fulfilled that's why getting the issue.

got the solution by using watch on conditional input boxes. below is the relevant code, ( here I am using json value as $watch do not invoke if changes in array, so change into json data)

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
           console.log('inside watch');
                return angular.toJson(vm.formdata.vehicles);
            }, function(nv, ov) {
                console.log(nv, ov);
                if (nv !== ov) {
                    var arr = Object.values(angular.fromJson(nv)); // change json > array
                    var arrVehicles = arr.map(Number); // change all array element from string to integer
                    console.log("vehicle Array:", arrVehicles);
                    var sum = arrVehicles.reduce(function(sum, cur) {
                        // console.log(sum, cur);
                        return sum + cur;
                    }, 0);
                    console.log("Boolean(sum)", Boolean(sum));
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.wheelForm.$setValidity("enough", Boolean(sum));
                        if( !Boolean(sum)) {
                            vm.invalidRequest = true;
                            vm.errorMessage = "At least 1 vehicle is required for the registration.";
                        } else {
                            vm.invalidRequest = false;
                            vm.errorMessage = "";
                        }
                    }, 0);
                } else {
                  $scope.wheelForm.$setValidity("enough", false);
                }
            });
```

and here is the [updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bhoe6M?p=preview)

---

### alternative approach

it can be achieved without `$watch` also, just added a method which manipulates total vehicles numbers and add it retuns as a flag for form submit button enable/disable.

## JS

```
 vm.isEnoughVehicles = function(vehicles) {
     if (angular.isDefined(vehicles)) {
         var arrVehicles = Object.values(vehicles).map(Number); // change array value from string to integer
         var total = arrVehicles.reduce(function(sum, prev) {
             var cur = isNaN(prev) ? 0 : prev;
             return sum + cur;
         }, 0);
         return (total > 0 ? true : false);
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 };
```

### HTML

```
 <button ng-disabled="wheelForm.$invalid || !vm.isEnoughVehicles(vm.formdata.vehicles)" class="btn btn-block btn-success" ng-click="vm.updateForm()">
          Update
        </button>
```

[update plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SKUSnj?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes in your plunker and think that all issues are fixed as i understood your points. Here is the link - https://plnkr.co/edit/bDzuBa?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.0" data-semver="3.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.0" data-semver="3.3.0" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ng-messages@1.3.16" data-semver="1.3.16" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="directive.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="container" ng-controller="AppController as vm">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="wheelForm" novalidate="">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error': wheelForm.username.$touched && wheelForm.username.$invalid }">
          <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.formdata.username" required="" />
          <div ng-if="wheelForm.username.$touched && wheelForm.username.$invalid" ng-messages="wheelForm.username.$error" class="has-error">
            <span ng-message="required">Please enter name.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <!--<label class="col-md-4"># of Bikes</label>{{wheelForm.vehicle_bike | json }}-->
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error': wheelForm.vehicle_bike.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_bike.$invalid }">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter 0 for no vehicles" name="vehicle_bike" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.formdata.vehicles.bike" validate-number="{min:1, max:16}" ng-required="true"  />
          <div ng-messages="wheelForm.vehicle_bike.$error" ng-if="wheelForm.vehicle_bike.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_bike.$invalid" class="text-danger">
            <!-- <span ng-message="parse">Enter 0 if no bike servlet required</span> -->
            <span ng-message="validRange">Number must be between 0 and 16.</span>
            <span ng-message="validNumber">Please enter valid Number.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <!--<label class="col-md-4"># of Cars</label>{{wheelForm.vehicle_car | json }}-->
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error': wheelForm.vehicle_car.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_car.$invalid }">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter 0 for no vehicles" name="vehicle_car" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.formdata.vehicles.car" ng-required="true" validate-number="{min:1, max:16}" required />
          <div ng-messages="wheelForm.vehicle_car.$error" ng-if="wheelForm.vehicle_car.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_car.$invalid" class="text-danger">
            <span ng-message="validRange">Number must be between 0 and 16.</span>
            <span ng-message="validNumber">Please enter valid Number.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <!--<label class="col-md-4"># of Cycles</label>{{wheelForm.vehicle_cycle | json }}-->
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error': wheelForm.vehicle_cycle.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_cycle.$invalid }">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter 0 for no vehicles" min="1" name="vehicle_cycle" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.formdata.vehicles.cycle" ng-required="true" validate-number="{min:1, max:16}" required />
          <div ng-messages="wheelForm.vehicle_cycle.$error" ng-if="wheelForm.vehicle_cycle.$touched && wheelForm.vehicle_cycle.$invalid" class="text-danger">
            <span ng-message="validRange">Number must be between 0 and 16.</span>
            <span ng-message="validNumber">Please enter valid Number.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-actions m-t-lg text-center">
        <button ng-disabled="wheelForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-block btn-success" ng-click="vm.updateForm()">
          Update
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's not working in your plunker. if I do not enter anything in rest 2 input box, form is not validated and even I added 0 to other 2 input boxes it throw validation errors

Comment: you set `ng-required="true"` and `required` attribute for all 3 input boxes  and also added `min` attribute to last input box , which won't works with input type text.